# Is there a way to force spam-filter to change their policy or remove them as recognized spam service?

Tags: spam-filter

As per mxtoolbox I got 1 blacklist still active for quite sometime now.

UCEPROTECTL1's is running on 7 day policy since last spam mail. This is too strict compared to the 98 other spam filters out there as per mxtoolbox. (Or at least to the other 4 that detected the problem)

I have no problem with our e-mail since it is hosted locally. But our domain is hosted outside the country and it run on a different IP. I contacted them but since it is the spam-filter's rule, there's nothing to be done but wait.

I do believe services like spam-filters should at lease be bounded by guidelines and standards for this matter. Otherwise problem on delivering valid (after the fix) e-mails will be disastrous.

Is there a way to force UCEPROTECT to change their policy or remove them as recognized spam service? Apart from contacting them in case they do not answer.

Currently they are charging for fast removal if you pay by PayPal.

I'm still looking for guideline/standard on how they should operate regarding this matter. Appreciate the help.

Comment: This falls under *"hire an expert"* to help sort the issues out. I don't think there's a problem here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Is there a way to *force* UCEProtect to change their policies?**

No. They're going to use whatever policy they feel works best for them.

You mention standards and guidelines. There **IS** [RFC 6471](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6471) , but do keep in mind that is considered "informational." Even if it were a standards-track RFC, its not like you can force UCEProtect to comply with it.

That said, if any blacklist operator went completely hayware, their list would cease to be useful. Receiving sites aren't forced to use any DNSBL, so ultimately the ability of a DNSBL to have any effect at all is dependent on its ongoing accuracy and usefulness.

Here's the real kicker though:  7-days might seem like a long time.. But, it typically takes at least 30 days for a negative reputation to clear up at many large ISPs. After a spam problem stops, UCEProtect and other blacklists will clear up their listings long before many of the big webmail providers will consider the IP clean. Heck, it is only a week. Wait it out. That's certainly faster than trying to "force" UCEProtect to change its policies.  That said, **Do NOT pay for delisting**. Blacklistings **should** be a protective measure, not a punitive one.

You can of course vote with your wallet and your mailserver, by  supporting and using DNSBLs of which you approve, and by refraining from supporting or using those of which you do not approve.

**Regarding MXToolBox**

Ignore them. MxToolBox still claims that SPEWS is one of the blacklists that check, even though that blacklist shut down years ago.

MxToolBox does sell various services to help with "blacklist removal". Keep in mind that if your server doesn't show up listed anywhere MxToolBox won't have anything to try to sell you.

**FULL DISCLOSURE:**

1. I use UCEProtect.
2. I hold a personal grudge against MxToolBox for various reasons.

Comment: Currently we have all mails delivered so I don't think they are popular enough to be used by our mail receivers. Thanks for info.

Comment: AFAIK they are more popular in Germany. Otherwise not so much. AFAIK most folks that do use UCEProtect, do NOT use it block unconditionally. Glad mail is getting delivered. If it was blocked for a while, it may not even have been related to the listing. Do keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Your description is a bit unclear. I don't know who you're sending TO or if the blocking server is part of your organization or not.

Regardless, you have a few options short of not doing business with people who use crappy spam filtering services.

- Find out why you were listed. If there's a problem, remediate it on your end.
- Establish a [smart host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_host) or relay that you can use for cases like this. There are also for-pay services that provide smart hosting. You don't mention your mail server type, but most mail solutions allow you to have scoped or granular rules that govern where mail for specific domains is routed.
- YOU can't force the UCEPROTECT to delist you. You *can* shame the recipient into not using that service to filter mail.
- If this is a regular business partner, request whitelisting.
- If this is your organization, use relay rules instead of filtering intra-company mail.
- Don't exchange money or PayPal funds to any spam blacklist. That's extortion.

Comment: I'm addressing it to the filtering server if it can be somehow controlled.

I did not mention our mail-server type cause it was not the problem. The problem is, our domain is hosted from another company who just relays email to us but we send out mail locally.

Thanks, for the other info.

Comment: That's still not clear. Who is having a problem?

Comment: It's our hosting company for our domain that had problems. It was resolved already. I run "blacklist:<our IP> all green. But when I run "blacklist:<our domain> we have blacklist.

Comment: Okay... But are you *actually* having a problem sending mail to someone?

Comment: Yes, since we use the "Announce myself as" = domain that was hosted.

Comment: UCEProtect does NOT list domains, rather only IP addresses. MxToolBox will commonly state that a domain has been listed by an IP only blacklist to scare the domain owner. Often it is the webserver's IP that is listed. Unless the webserver is also the outbound MTA, that is not a problem if it is listed.

Comment: My favorite example of this is with the Spamhaus PBL. Some folks request their own webservers to be listed, since their webservers dont send mail. Kindof a security-in-depth approach. MxToolBox will of course flag that as a "Problem" and that the domain is listed for spamming, and whole bunch of other non-sense.